# How to display succes or error message in MVC with Javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, error-handling

I'm wondering how to display a succes or error message on succes or fail by a controller action in my MVC project with bootstrap. For example I got the following  action:

**Input:**

[image]

**Javascript method to send data to controller:**

```
              //Sends data filled in in modal to backend.
              $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                    var datastring = $("#myForm").serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/ApiBroker/AddApi",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: datastring,
                    });
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                })
            })
```

**Controller method:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddApi(ApiRedirect model)
    {
        var data = model;
        try
        {
            List<ApiRedirect> list = dbProducts.ApiRedirects.ToList();
            int companyID = dbProducts.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyName == model.Company.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault().CompanyID;
            int mappingID = dbProducts.MappingNames.Where(x => x.Name == model.MappingName.Name).FirstOrDefault().MappingID;
            ApiRedirect api = new ApiRedirect();
            api.ApiName = model.ApiName;
            api.CompanyID = companyID;
            api.ApiURL2 = model.ApiURL2;
            api.MappingID = mappingID;
            api.ResponseType = model.ResponseType;
            dbProducts.ApiRedirects.Add(api);
            dbProducts.SaveChanges();
            return View ();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

If the method AddUser added the user into my database I want to display a error message, and if the user was not added I want to display a error message. I dont know how to achieve this, any suggetions?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

So the alert works but the POST call is getting the following internal server error:

[image]

Comment: You can use a ViewBag, TempData, or even, since you are using ajax post, you can return a string and display that to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you ajax needs to be updated to use a success or failure

```
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/ApiBroker/AddApi",
            data: datastring,
            dataType: 'json',
            success:
                function(data){
                    //... put your logic here 
             },
            error:
                function(){ alert('error'); }
        });
```

Secondly you need to update your controller action to return a IHttpActionResult where you can specify a Response message.

If you look at this

[HttpResponseMessage](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/036f9e/httpresponsemessage-in-webapi166/)

Comment: Somehow this code giving me the alert "Error" but the data gets added to my database.

Comment: `Success` / `Error` is not always necessary though. mostly depends on the return of the method you are calling

Comment: @JamesS yes, not necessary but as the OP said he needs to know the status.

Comment: @NielsStenden I forgot the add the datatype to the Ajax call, where are you getting an error? please post your code.

Comment: @NielsStenden I would use the following code for the URL within the ajax request: url: '@Url.Action("ACTION", "CONTROLLER")', That error is saying that MVC is searching and can't find the controller/action. Can you post the full controller code if the URL doesn't work. Also decorate your method with [HttpPost]

Comment: Hi @Rav, the data gets added to my database so the controller does work. However I'm returning View() after completion and I think that is where I'm getting the error from.

Comment: @NielsStenden you need to return a IHttpReponseMessage like the link I added, are you using .Net Core? if so return the ActionResult.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195808/discussion-between-rav-and-nielsstenden).